# No errors in developer console - but my jQuery script does not work on certain IE browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to debug jQuery code if the Developer Console is not showing any errors?

I have written a script that lets users shuffle a deck of cards by moving their mouse (or finger on a touch device), select 3 of them, and then it takes them to a page with the cards as a URL parameter.

It works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and many other browsers... but I have received error reports from users saying the script does not work. I had one user fill out a http://supportdetails.com page -> and the script was not working on their IE 10 / Windows 7 / JavaScript enabled setup.

I have run the script many times in the JavaScript Console (Chrome) and there does not appear to be any errors... but I looked in Analytics - and there is no traffic on the /done/ page from IE 8 (there is some from IE 10).

Clearly I have done something wrong!

I have uploaded the code to www.jpony.com/cards/index.html if you are curious... but my main question is: how can you debug code on a Mac if there are no errors showing, and it works on all mac friendly browsers?

Comment: I noticed in loading your code page that the cards will not finish shuffling unless I move my mouse over the page - if I leave my mouse still, the spinner will continue spinning, but cards won't appear on the page.

Comment: Yes - the cards are shuffled based on unixtimestap - position of x and y coordinates of mouse (or finger)

Comment: The solution is simple: Drop support for IE, **all versions**. If enough of us do it, hopefully someday Microsoft will too...

Comment: @danludwig That's not a good solution at all.  IE accounts for 20-30% of all web traffic.  You'd have to be nuts to alienate 20-30% of potential customers.  A better idea is to take the time to understand the differences between the different browsers and their implementation of the W3C & ECMA standards.  All browsers deviate from the spec in some places.  IE10+ are pretty decent browsers, certainly compared to IE9-.